# Is there a word for the opening of a song?

Tags: single-word-requests, songs

I'm looking for a word (if such exists) for the opening of a song.

Specifically, the part before the singer starts singing the lyrics, often a 30 seconds to 1 minute solo instrumental at the beginning of the song. Like how the word [kick-off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kick+off), is used for conversation.

Does such a word exist?

Comment: If the intro is just a couple of notes, it's usually called a "pickup", or [_anacrusis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacrusis).

Comment: ....The *opening*

Comment: The word you are looking for  is "prelude" see e.g.: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prelude (unfortuantely I do not have enough reputation for a real answer since the question has been protected)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just to expand on [Josh's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/379409/116151): the term *introduction* is mostly used in the shortened form: [***intro***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intro), especially when it comes to contemporary music.

Comment: As in "_Beat the intro_" quizzes where you have to guess the name of the song before the words start.

Comment: Also of note, the instrumental ending of a song is often referred to as the "outro", despite "outroduction" not being an actual word.

Comment: Worth noting that even though they sound the same, the etymology for [in](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in&allowed_in_frame=0) is not the same for [introduction](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=introduction). That is why @HarrisonPaine is correct.

Comment: This answer is more correct (which is to say more common place) than the accepted answer.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine: And musical bits between verses are sometimes "midtros".

Comment: by far the most accurate answer on this page.

Answer (score 45):

***[Introduction](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/introduction):***

> - a preliminary part, as of a book, musical composition, or the like, leading up to the main part.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55857/discussion-on-answer-by-josh-is-there-a-word-for-the-opening-of-a-song).

Answer (score 5):

It's referred to as the [overture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overture); that's specifically an instrumental opening.

Comment: Thanks @ulatekh - from what I understand _overture_ applies on opera music, so it could be the alternative choice for _intro_ when talking about that type of music.

Comment: Well, that or pretentious rock songs -- Rush's 2112 album begins with a song called "Overture", and Electric Light Orchestra has a song called "10538 Overture". Disclaimer: I'm huge fans of both those bands.